# Downloading Android Source Code Using SDK Manager?

Tags: android, sdk

SDK Manager gives me the option to download the source code of any Android version. I can explore the source code in the `sources` folder inside the `android-sdk`.

However, For the version prior to API 14, I can't find that option to download!

Any one knows how to download it? Or why I can't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 3.x version of Android the sources were not released. So for these versions I can understand why there is no such option. For 2.x versions, there is no such option in my case also.

For 2.x version you can use a special plugin called Android sources. You can find instructions [here](https://code.google.com/p/adt-addons/).

The second option is to download Android sources. In the properties of your android-ver.jar you can set the location of the sources.